# Why do we get fat only to a certain point?

Tags: weight-gain

I was just thinking and wondering about it.

Earlier in my life i ate a lot of snacks and drank soda. Ate way more and way more unhealthy and didn't do any sports but never got heavier than 78kg. Now i live way healthier. I eat healthy, eat less, do sports and have about 70kg. But if i was to quit sports and get back into my old eating habits I would put up 3-4kg in a month i'm sure of it.

**But why wouldn't I get fatter after a certain point(78kg for me)?**

If I take more kcal in than I put out, shouldn't I theretically gain those 3-4 pounds every month as long as i continue to live like that and soon reach the hundrets?

Comment: I'm uncertain what you're asking.  Could you please rephrase your question(s) using the word "not" fewer (or no) times?

Comment: There is nothing relating to a fitness program in this question. This is a theoretical question that isn't really on topic for the site.

Comment: @JohnP can you reccomend another SE site where it fits?

Comment: @MansNotHot - I'm not really sure there is one. Health would reject it too. If I had to take a stab, it's that all tissue requires X amount of calories to maintain. If you eat 5000 calories a day, your body stabilizes at a level of fat/muscle (depending on workouts, etc) at that level. To gain more, you need to eat more or move less. And so on.

Comment: @JohnP Thanks for the stab :) Should i delete the question then?

Comment: @MansNotHot - Up to you, really. :)